# How do i add width to an object in code?

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
var widthx = document.getElementById('testx');
var newwidth = document.getElementById('mycontent').style.width = widthx.width + 45 //not working
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#testx
{
width: 950px;
}

#mycontent
{
width: 800px; //this width needs to change from javascript to 950 + 45 px
}

....
```

I want to change mycontent's width to be testx width + 45 pixels (px). Anybody knows how to do this in javascript ?

Comment: Try doing a `console.log` or `alert` on both `widthx` and `widthx.width` - this will help you find your problem.

Comment: What happens? `style.width` will be a string, if you want to perform mathematical operations you have to convert it into a number first.

Comment: interesting, i know that, but i don't know the syntax

Comment: @JarM, what happened when you tried `console.log` (you did try it right, or do you not care about solving this problem?), and what does that tell you about your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
#testx
{
    width: 950px;
}

#mycontent
{
    width: 800px; //this width needs to change from javascript to 950 + 45 px
}
</style>

<!-- YOUR HTML HERE -->

<script language="javascript">
function onlyNumber(str) {
    str = str.toString();
    return str.replace(/\D/g, '');
}
var widthx = onlyNumber(document.getElementById('testx').style.width) * 1;
document.getElementById('mycontent').style.width = (widthx + 45) + "px";
</script>
```

With jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    function onlyNumber(str) {
        str = str.toString();
        return str.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var widthx = onlyNumber($("#testx").css("width")) * 1;
       $("#mycontent").css("width", (widthx + 45) + "px");
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#testx
{
    width: 950px;
}

#mycontent
{
    width: 800px; //this width needs to change from javascript to 950 + 45 px
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- YOUR HTML HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need content to change, put JS in the bottom. PS: With jQuery is more easy. Try now.

Comment: i don't have time to learn new language, i am trying this the whole day and you examples don't work, not a single 1, now you telling me i should go and learn a new framework to solve this simple problem. no thx.

Comment: I recommend you to study jQuery, you will not regret it. I put a
example for you to see.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems.

First, `widthx.width` doesn't exist. You should use `widthx.offsetWidth`.

Second, a simple number is not a correct value for `…style.width`. Use `widthx.offsetWidth + 45 + 'px'` for instance.

Comment: @JarM, the last sentence provides a direct example (though it preserves the invalud `widthx.width` call).

Comment: Can you please write me those 3 words after: getElementById('mycontent').style.width =

Comment: @JarM: What is "write me those 3 words after: ..."?

Comment: My bad, there was some errors in my comments.

@JarM: I've created an example based on your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Lsd/ As you can see, #mycontent is wider thanks to the JavaScript code.